# Convert jQuery UI colorpicker slider to jQuery Mobile version

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, canvas

I'm not at all a js programmer, so I'm getting really confused looking at the code inside the jquery mobile library (they don't have good comments at all). I've created a colorpicker slider using jQuery UI, you can see the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZMwz/) - I'm looking for help creating a version of my fiddle using jquery mobile instead or any pointers with where to start.

I see they use a different method to alter the elements, so I attempted to alter them, such as:

```
    domSlider.setAttribute( "id", "slider-horiz" );
    domSlider.setAttribute( "role", "application" );
```

I'm not sure how to implement the functions I need to the slider itself, like in jQuery UI I was able to do this in my html document (as evident in the fiddle):

```
    $(function() {
    var box = $('#box')[0];

    $("#slider-horiz").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        value: 0,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            box.style.background = 'hsl(' + ui.value + ', 100%, 50%)';
            var clr = $('#box').css('background-color');
            $('#box').attr('data-color', clr).trigger('click');
            $('#slider-handle').css('background-color', clr);
            if (ui.value == 0) {
                $('#box').attr('data-color', 'hsl(' + ui.value + ', 0%, 0%)').trigger('click');
                $('#slider-handle').css('background-color', '#000');
            }
            if (ui.value == 360) {
                $('#box').attr('data-color', 'hsl(' + ui.value + ', 100%, 100%)').trigger('click');
                $('#slider-handle').css('background-color', '#fff');
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7F9eZ/

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <form>
                    <input name="slider-1" id="slider-1" min="0" max="360" value="0" type="range"/>
                    <a href="#colored_sketch" id="box" data-color="" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 30px; height: 30px; background: #000; display: inline-block;"></a>                    
                </form>                                
                <canvas id='colored_sketch' width='800' height='300'></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){ 
    var box = $('#box')[0];
    $('#colored_sketch').sketch();

    $(document).on( "slidestop", "#slider-1", function( event, ui ) {
        box.style.background = 'hsl(' + $(this).val() + ', 100%, 50%)';
        var clr = $('#box').css('background-color');
        $('#box').attr('data-color', clr).trigger('click');        
    });    
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-slider-track {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/lHQxra5.png) repeat-x !important;
    width: 200px !important;
    margin: 0 15px 0 15px !important;
}

#slider-1 {
    display: none;
}

#box {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: wow, totally not expected, but much appreciated - is jquery mobile just not capable of doing the real-time updating that was present in my fiddle? As in, updating the color of the box as the slider moves. I noticed the slidestop and slidestart (which I can't find in their docs of course).

Comment: It is capable and official documentation exist you only need a PhD in archeology to find it: http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/ ;)

Comment: edit: nevermind, I got the color working, just not in real-time.